# Error File Not Found when run Java file by CMD

Tags: java, cmd

I'm having a trouble when run file .java by cmd. When I run, it appear error like this   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpMwi.png [enter image description here][1]
Thanks for your help.
Btw, this is my code

```
    /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Stack s1 = new Stack(); 
    Stack s2 = new Stack(); 
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        s1.push(i);
        i++;
    }
}
public void KeyPress (KeyEvent undo, Stack s1, Stack s2)
{
    if(undo.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z){
        s1.pop();
        int j = 1;
        s2.push(j);
        j++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your file isn't in that folder. Simple as that.

Comment: you should change the folder in which your file is present,and then try again

Answer (score 0):

You have to know your file path and type:

Example your file in desktop:

Type in cmd:

```
CD C:\Users\TGDD\Desktop
javac Undo.java
```

You have to know exactly your file path do run this.